# Hint to force locks between 2 Select clauses

Tags: sql-server, locking

I have a process that run in parallel on several threads and also on several machines.

In summary, the process has to 'lock' a row in a table named 'Queue' and then retrieves some columns from the locked row and do some other logic operations.

My objective is to do this with the best performance: reliable info and fastest way.

This is how I design the query of the process:

```
UPDATE  MQ.dbo.Queue
            SET     queue_lock = 1,
                    Queue_Key = 'H10_P19_T0_19032017T193926148',
                    Queue_LockDate = getdate()
            where   Queue_ID = (select top 1 Queue_ID 
                                    from MQ.dbo.Queue with (nolock)
                                    where queue_lock = 0
                                    and QueueName_ID = 16
                                    order by queue_id) 
            And     isnull(queue_lock,0) = 0


GetQueue (Datasource=mydatabase, Time=1.12 ms, Records=0) in F:\Web\Process\Component\MQ.cfc

Select  top 1 Queue_ID,Queue_Message
            From    MQ.dbo.Queue with (nolock)
            Where   QueueName_ID = 16
                    and queue_lock = 1
                    and Queue_Key = 'H10_P19_T0_19032017T193926148'
```

The Queue_key consist of:

- Host_ID
- Process_ID
- Thread_ID
- Datestamp

This choice (Queue_key) was taken to tolerate parallelism on the process with reliable results.

My problem is that in some cases the second query (`Select top 1....`) returns 0 records even so it should not, since there are a lot of waiting row in the table 'Queue'.

And the percentage of this case rise when I rise the parallelism.

I know where is the gap in this 2 queries but I search for a way to overcome it and I need your help doing this.

In fact, the gap is in the select clause of the first query (the sub-query): Since select clauses hold only shared lock and 2 shared locks (2 select) don't block each other (are compatible), it is possible that 2 threads running in parallel retrieve the same row and only one update take place (because update hold exclusive lock on the row). So the second query (`select top 1 ...`) returns result for only one thread.

So I need through a lock hint (maybe updlock or rowlock), to don't allow 2 select clauses to retrieve the same row, without degrading a lot the response time.

Rq: the with (nolock) hint was added to increase the response time since shared lock is compatible with another shared lock (either with this hint or without it).

Can anyone have a suggestion for this type of scenarios?

Comment: Can you capture GetDate() into a variable (@LockDate) before the UPDATE, then use that variable (@LockDate) IN the UPDATE and add an additional check in the 2nd query to also include @LockDate as part of the WHERE criteria?

Comment: See https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Answer (score 1):

If you add an OUTPUT clause to your UPDATE statement you could do all the work using one statement thus eliminating race conditions

Available on SQL Server 2005 and later

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-update-statements

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `BEGIN TRANS ... COMMIT TRANS` to encapsulate your data?

You can combine that with the WITH (rowlock) syntax:

```
Begin Transaction Queue1
Begin Try
  update [...]

  Select [...] From [...]
  With (RowLock)

  Commit Transaction Queue1
End Try
Begin Catch
  Rollback Transaction Queue1
End Catch
```

[Select With clause information here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx).

Exhaustive discussion on [SQL Server locking strategies here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx).